# Trouble using SaveAsCopy in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble having ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsCopy work on VBA.

I'm very new to programming modules so bear with me.

I created a module to help automate the generation of new production orders. I created a model for the production order form where the user would fill in all the necessary information and then would run the vba module to automatically print the production order and then save a copy of the file in a different directory with the file name changed to include the production order number.

The point of the module is to:

Update counter everytime I run the module

Print the active sheet

Save a copy of the file with the current information

Clear contents of all fields to be filled next time

This is the code

```
Sub PrintAndSave()

    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim FileName As String 'Name of the file
    Dim FullPath As String 'Path of the file
    On Error Resume Next


        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = Counter
        
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").NumberFormat = "00000" 'sets the number of digits for displaying the counter on the file
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Text
        
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
        FileName = "Ordem de Producao " & Range("B2").Value 'defines the name for the file
        FullPath = "M:INTEC\Produção\Ordens De Produção\Intec" + "\" + FileName + ".xlsm" 'defines the path to save the new file
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsCopy FullPath
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        MsgBox "Ordem de produção salva em " & FullPath 'displays path where the file was saved
        
        Counter = Counter + 1 'adds to counter variable to keep incrementing
        
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = Counter
        
        ActiveSheet.Range("B3:G3").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("B4:C4").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("E4:G4").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("B5:C5").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("E5:G5").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("C6:G6").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("A8:G9").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("A11:G13").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("A16:G21").ClearContents
        
    
End Sub
```

What works:

Setting the file name

Clearing the contents of the cells

Updating the counter on cell "B2"

Print command

What doesn't work:

Counter does not increment

Copy file is never created or saved

Thing I tried:

Changing FullPath to direct to my local desktop path (model file and copy file are/should be in the storage server)

Tried creating a module just to save a copy of the file, which also did not work.

Comment: It's `SaveCopyAs` not `SaveAsCopy`

Comment: Your counter isn't public/global so the variable is reset/redim'd every time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806425/public-static-variable-in-excel-vba) for an example.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Setting a public variable in the header worked, thanks

Comment: @Rory changed the syntax but still doesn't save a new file. Do you think there might be a problem with spaces or special characters in the path name?

Comment: You are missing a backslash after the `M:`. This is why you shouldn't just put `On Error Resume Next` at the start of the code and hope for the best - it makes it very hard to know where things are actually going wrong!

Comment: @Rory fair point. All working now. What would you suggest as an error commannd instead of Resume next? Tbh, I just copied what I've seen from other modules I copied

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is ok if used wisely. It should be limited to as short a lifetime as possible though, not just put at the start of any routine that might hit an error somewhere. Also note it doesn't **handle** errors, it just **ignores** them, which can be dangerous.

Comment: In your case, there's no need for it. If there is an error and others might be using your code, you can opt for some (basic) error handling like quite clearly is explained [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/). `On Error Resume Next` is handy if you expect issues with for example looping through sheets based on names in a range and not reaching one isn't a cause for a restart.